# Exporting an animation (Time Series) map through QGIS2web plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, time-series

I simply would like to know if it is possible to export an animation map using the **QGIS2web plugin** so I may display a time series map on the web through the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

See if you can find a copy of time2web, which does exactly what you want:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2016-October/044997.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! So I downloaded: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_time2web/, the repository and set the path for qgis. Although it is a good representation for the data, but I was looking for more of a play button to play the animation through the time series, unless im just ignorant at the moment.

Comment: Ah, apologies. I misremembered what time2web did. There is the Time Manager plugin which could be worth a try, but I don't know what format it exports to, and hence how web-friendly it is.

Comment: No problem! Yes, so that is how my time series map was created through the Time Manager Plugin. I was wanting to represent it on the web like the "qgis2web" does, if it is possible of course?